# Declare inner class name as part of another declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

While attempting to define a class by the pimpl idiom, I tried to save a line of code by rolling the class forward declaration into the pimpl definition.

```
class A
{
public:
    class Impl *pimpl;
};
```

The above declaration compiles fine. What doesn't work, is the attempt to *define* `A::Impl`. [As the program bellow demonstrates](https://ideone.com/Zd8R2B):

```
class A
{
public:
    class Impl *pimpl;
};

class A::Impl
{

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

It results with:

> error: qualified name does not name a class before '{' token

Now, one can introduce a new class name, by an elaborate type specifier, as part of another declaration. But it is in fact `Class ::Impl` which is [introduced](https://ideone.com/SfScvK).

```
class A
{
public:
    class Impl *pimpl;
};

class Impl
{

};

int main() {
    Impl i;
    A a;
    a.pimpl = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it that a forward declaration on it's own line (as the idiom is often used), will introduce `A::Impl`, but when declared as part of the pointer definition, will introduce `::Impl`?

**Update**

I'm not asking how to make the idiom work. My question is why the single line

```
class Impl *pimpl;
```

doesn't have the same effect as the two lines

```
class Impl;
Impl *pimpl;
```

In the context of a class definition.

I'm baffled because the name becomes properly qualified when [something similar is done in the context of a namespace](https://ideone.com/K4bv3X).

```
namespace A
{
    class Impl *pimpl;
};

class A::Impl
{

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the standard provides an answer as usual. And mandates it explicitly.

Quoting [3.4.4 [basic.lookup.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab) paragraph 2 (empahsis mine):

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* has no *nested-name-specifier*, and **unless the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the following form**:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;*
>
> **the identifier is looked up according to [basic.lookup.unqual]** but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared
>   (...)
>   If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* **and this lookup does not find a previously declared type-name**, or if the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;*
>
> **the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the class-name as described in** [basic.scope.pdecl].

And [3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl) paragraph 7 (emphasis again mine):

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> -- for a declaration of the form
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;*
>
> the identifier is declared to be a class-name in the scope that contains the declaration, otherwise
>
> -- for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key identifier*
>
> if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that contains the declaration; **otherwise**, except as a friend declaration, **the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration**. [ Note: These rules also apply within templates.  — end note ] [ Note: Other forms of elaborated-type-specifier do not declare a new name, and therefore must refer to an existing type-name. See [basic.lookup.elab] and [dcl.type.elab].  — end note ]

**The declaration** in the last emphasized line seems to refer to the declaration of the class where the elaborated class specifier appears. So in our case it adds the `Impl` into the namespace that contains the class `A`, the global scope. But the same will apply to any namespace. [Case and point](http://ideone.com/VVBlNO):

```
namespace E
{
    class A
    {
        class Impl *pImpl;  
    };
}

class E::Impl
{

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your `A` declaration slightly:

```
class A
{
public:
    class Impl;

    Impl *pimpl;
};
```

Now, everything will work as expected.

You have to tell the compiler that `Impl` is an inner class, first.

```
class A
{
public:
    class Impl *pimpl;
};
```

This tells the compiler that `pimpl` is a pointer to some top level class named `Impl`, rather than an inner class.

Comment: I know how to make it work as expected. That's not my question. I guess I should remove the `pimpl` tag.